# SQL Query to display multiple records from same table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am creating a database for a small start-up college athletic recruitment firm. Basically what I am trying to do is to pull high school players stats from two years at the varsity level, and display them in one row if possible. (I know it sounds messy, but for the sake of the commercial web publisher we are using it is easier this way for me create it.) Example table structure can be seen below:

```
Player ID, YearId, Points
10, 2010, 120
11, 2010, 90
10, 2011, 160
11, 2011, 173
```

Desired Results:

```
10, 2010, 120, 2011, 160

11, 2010, 90, 2011, 173
```

I am new to MySQL, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes it is. My apologies, that's just what the name of the field is in the database table.

Comment: Then my answer should give you what you're looking for

Answer (score 2):

This will give you a rolling previous two years, using the current year and previous automatically from when the query is run:

```
SELECT p.PlayerId, p.YearId AS PreviousYear, p.Points AS PreviousPoints
   , p2.YearId AS CurrentYear, p2.Points AS CurrentPoints
FROM Player AS p
LEFT JOIN Player AS p2 ON p.PlayerId = p2.PlayerId
   AND p.YearId = p2.YearId - 1
WHERE p2.YearId = YEAR(NOW())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select
playerid,group_concat(concat_ws(',',yearid,points) order by yearid) as merged
from table
where yearid >= year(curdate() - interval 1 year)
group by playerid
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is really only two years you're looking for, you could join:

```
SELECT t1.playerid,t1.yearid,t1.points,t2.yearid.t2.points 
FROM table t1 
LEFT JOIN table t2 
ON t1.playerid = t2.playerid 
WHERE t1.yearid = 2010 AND t2.yearid = 2011;
```

If you need a more flexible way, you can always go with subqueries, but I guess you'll come to the point where you want to do this kind of restructuring on the script side instead of in the database. Relational Databases just don't perform good with such unstructured data.